# Format cell fill based on a range of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Could anyone advise how to format the fill of cell based on percentile ranges? So for example, I have a row of values. I'd like to format the fill on those cells such that I have cell fill colour for three conditions: above the 90th, between 10th and 90th and below the 10th percentile. If I try to create a conditional formatting rule with a 3-color scale, I am not sure how to format the 10th to 90th percentile range.

So basically what I am asking is how to format a row of cells thresholding on a range.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f). Perhaps you should simply use more than a single rule.

Comment: I have looked at Conditional Formatting. However, it isn't clear to me how to apply a formula that covers all the cells that I am looking to format if I was what is frankly a fairly simple condition (i.e. between two values).

Comment: You would have **three** separate rules and order them in priority.  The first formula would be `>.9` the second would be `>.1` the third is optional as it will be all the rest and can be the default formatting.  So due to priority, if the number is between .1 and .9 the second rule will fire, it it is above the .9 only the first rule will fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Excel 2013, might be slightly different path for older versions.

Highlight the cell range you want.

`Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule`

Under New Rule, there should be 6 options, choose option **`Format only top or bottom ranked values`**. Choose **Top**, **10** (or whatever number you want), and click the box for **% of the selected range**.

Hit Format and go to Fill, and choose a background color.

Do the same thing, but now choose Bottom instead of Top.

This will highlight the top x% and bottom y%. Also, if you're open, you should also try Icon Sets and you can use Green/Yellow/Red circles or arrows to help.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This indeed works well EXCEPT it does not highlight the 10-90 range. I know it is trivial but I'd like to have those cells formatted with a background colour as well. Any thoughts there?

Comment: @boshek set all the cells to the color you want these to be.  then when they do not satisfy one of the two conditions it will revert to what the cell is set otherwise it will use the conditional formatting.

Comment: Is it possible to add a grouping variable to this process? So conduct conditional formatting for multiple rows but only have that given row set the percentile criteria for that row?